# Why does fsockget timeout in this example when using single quotes for some of the text?

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm testing Salesforce's WebToLead form using this simple example http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Simple_Web2Lead_Implementation.

When I changed the double quotes (used to concatenate the `$header` values) into single quotes, I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 23
```

When I change them back to double quotes, everything works fine. What am I missing?

Here is a simplified version you can use if you have a Salesforce developer account:

```
<?php
//do quality checks on the incoming data here.

//then bundle the request and send it to Salesforce.com
$req  = "&lead_source=". urlencode("test");
$req .= "&first_name=" . urlencode("first name test");

$req .= "&debug=" . urlencode("1");
$req .= "&oid=" . urlencode("<your oid>"); 
$req .= "&retURL=" . "";
$req .= "&debugEmail=" . urlencode("<your email>");

$header  = 'POST /servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8 HTTP/1.0\r\n';
$header .= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n';
$header .= 'Host: www.salesforce.com\r\n';
$header .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($req) . '\r\n\r\n';
$fp = fsockopen ('www.salesforce.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
echo "No connection made";
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024); // error is thrown here
echo $res;
}
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `'\r\n\r\n'` won't be evaluated into the actual characters, while `"\r\n\r\n"` will.

Since they aren't being evaluated properly, the header will be improperly formed, which would explain your timeout.

Comment: Guess I missed `Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.` when looking at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php